# How to search for a String in java if I have more than one array and I want to search in all of them?

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem1 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        String search =input.nextLine();
        String arr1[] = {"Ranitidine","Seclo","Aceclofenac","Finix","Stemetile"};
        String arr2[] = {"Raine","Seclo","Aceofenac","Finix","temetile"};
        String arr3[] = {"Ranitie","Seclo","Aclofenac","Fix","Stile"};
        String arr4[] = {"Ranitide","Sclo","Acecofenac","Finx","Stemile"};
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried search in one array? If you know how to search in one array why not just do it for all arrays?

Comment: `Stream.of(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4).flatMap(Stream::of).anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(search))`

Comment: hehe @shmosel it's beautiful but also not gonna help a beginner :) i mean he will not understand

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String key = "Jones";
        String[ ] list = new String [100];   // instantiate the array
        for ( int i=0; i<100; i++)     // fill the array
             list [ i ]=Console.readLine("Enter name:  ");
        int count = search (list, key);    // invoke the method
        System.out.println("Count = " + count);
    }
    public static int search(String [ ] list, String key) //method to find "Jones"
    {
         int i, count = 0;
         for( i = 0; i< list.length; i++)
         {
              if (list [ i ].equals( key ))
                 count = count+1;
         }
         return (count);
    }
```

/////////////.............

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // adding element in search string array
        String[] searchArray = {"object", "search", "word"};

        boolean searchArrayResult = false;

        // This block search all string array
        // if string find in array it will break from 
        // string array loop and return true value.
        for (String str : searchArray){
            searchArrayResult = str.contains("wor");
            if(searchArrayResult){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Search string Array result :"+searchArrayResult);
    }
```